# Why can't I use substring with a slash?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can use any other character but when I use a \ I'm getting a syntax error.

I searched on Google but I couldn't find anything. I tried with single quotes and double quotes but both give a syntax error. I also tried turning the `\` into a variable, but that also gave me a syntax error.

```
 var s = $(".originalunc").val();
 s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\"));
 alert(s);
```

Comment: You need to escape the slash: `s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\\"));`. Your code will throw a syntax error.

Comment: doesnt work. My alert is blank

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `\` character has special meaning. It begins an escape sequence.

When you type `"\"` you are saying:

1. `"`: Start string literal
2. `\`: Begin escape sequence
3. `"`: Add a quote character to the string (because that is what the `\"` escape sequence means) instead of "End string literal".

Then the rest of the line is inside the string literal.

Then you have a new line, which is an error.

You need to escape the `\` if you want to use one as data.

```
indexOf("\\")
```

Comment: I am out of votes. Shouldn't this be closed as a typo instead?

Comment: @PraveenKumar — No. The problem is that the OP doesn't understand how escape sequences work, not that they misspelt something.

Comment: I wouldn't say so as the OP seems unaware of how character escaping works. If the issue had been caused by a mis-typed variable name then I'd say yes.

Comment: Is the slash case sensitive?  ;)

Comment: @Quentin Since the second one didn't escape, being a half-escape tag, why not it didn't show up in the output? Strange. If it was `\t` or `\"` it would show up as those chars, but what if it was just `\ `, it could show up as itself right?

Comment: @PraveenKumar — From [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.8.4): "The CV of NonEscapeCharacter :: SourceCharacter but not one of EscapeCharacter or LineTerminator is the SourceCharacter character itself."

Comment: Sorry i'm still learning and i didnt know. I tried the following but my alert is blank. The input value is \\server\test . I need to drop everything after \\server\          var s = $(".originalunc").val();
   s = s.substring(0, s.indexOf("\\"));
   alert(s);

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```
     var myString = $(".originalunc").val().split("\\").pop();
     alert(myString);
```